# Changing a select box's value using JQuery when the select box is dynamically populated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a PHP code that dynamically populates the select box such as:

```
for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++) {
  echo '<select id='s_.$i.'> <option> Yes </option> <option> No </option> </select>';
}
```

Now every time a user does something, I want to set the option value of the select box into a certain value  using JQuery something like:

```
 $("#target").click(function() {
    $("#s_1").val('No'); // #1 is the ID of the select box 1 
});
```

But it doesn't work. I've also tried to retrieve the element by DocumentFindById function, but it only works well when I tested with static HTML. It fails when I make these select boxes dynamically using PHP. Is there any way to make this work?

Thanks.

added comment) Sorry, I did not use a number id in my code. I thought it would be a simpler example. Using a string id, it still doesn't work at all.. :(

Comment: see is any error in console

Answer (score 0):

Use `on()` as follows:

```
$(document).on('click', '#target', function () {
    $("#1").val('No'); // #1 is the ID of the select box 1 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
   $(function() {
       $("#target").click(function() {
         $("#1").val('No'); // #1 is the ID of the select box 1 
       });
   });
</script>
```

Note: Don't use #1 as id

Comment: Sorry, I used that number id as a simplified example. In my code, the id is a string. It still does not work :(

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your code doesn't work on dynamically generated html? Maybe this will work:

```
$("#target").on('click',function() {
    $("#1").val('No'); // #1 is the ID of the select box 1 
});
```

The only change here is the [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).